# I'm trying to use a jquery but getting two errors:

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

In netbeans i created a php code and did this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="flexslider.css" type="text/css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(window).load(function() {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider();
  });
</script>

        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="slideShow">
        <?php
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
//$allowed_types="(\.jpg$)|(\.png$)|(\.jpeg$)|(\.gif$) |(\.Gif$)";
$allowed_types = array('png','jpg','jpeg','gif');
$imageDir = 'Images';
/*
    Assumes this .php is being run from the http root on the same
    domain as the desired image files.
*/

$handle = opendir($imageDir);
while (($imgPath = readdir($handle)) !== false) if (
    in_array(
        strtolower(pathinfo($imgPath, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)),
        $allowed_types
    )) echo '
    <img src="', $imageDir, '/', $imgPath, '" alt="slide" />';
closedir($handle);
        ?>
        </div>
        <div class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li>       
      <img src="Images/radar000025.GIF" />
    </li>
    <li>       
      <img src="Images/radar000814.GIF" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

    </body>
</html>
```

I uploaded the php file later to my host server and then i'm getting two errors:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < jquery.flexslider.js:1
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function SlideTestHtml.html:15

The goal here is to do two things:

1. Using the jquery in this case:

   [flexslider](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/)
2. To use the php script inside  to get all images from a server directory to aray and use this array instead the lines

How can i fix the errors and how can i put the images from the directory in array and use this array insteas

Comment: Well based on that error, looks like a `<` (lt bracket) got echoed out into the script portion of your rendered HTML page from the PHP call. We cannot diagnose that because you did not show us what the PHP script is doing...

Comment: Mr.Polywhir i created new php project in netbeans 8.0.1 and i have only one file index.php and what i wanted to do is to use the flexslider jquery: http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/ in my code and that the images to display will be from the php array code.

Comment: You right i updated the question with the php code.The php script in <?php and ?> should add to array the images from a directory and then i want  to loop over the array and use it to display the images with the flexslider jquery.

Comment: The php script is working i tested it before it does get all the images to array  i just don't know how to fix the erros and how to use the images in the array with the flexslider.

Answer (score -1):

Try to put your js code at the bottom of div with images..
For the reference please go to "view-source:http://flexslider.woothemes.com/"

Search for:

```
<script src="jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
      $(window).load(function() {
        $('.flexslider').flexslider();
      });
    </script>
```

And make a note where the code is located.

```
    <div class="flexslider">
      <ul class="slides">
         <li>       
      <img src="files/radar-simulation-files/radar000004.GIF" />
    </li>
    <li>       
      <img src="files/radar-simulation-files/radar000005.GIF" />
    </li>
    <li>       
      <img src="files/radar-simulation-files/radar000006.GIF" />
    </li>
   <li>       
      <img src="files/radar-simulation-files/radar002202.GIF" />
    </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  <script src="jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
      $(window).load(function() {
        $('.flexslider').flexslider();
      });
    </script>
```

Comment: That will do absolutely nothing (the code is wrapped in a load event handler!). It certainly won't deal with the error message quoted.

Comment: <script src="jquery.flexslider.js"></script> have to be at the bottom as well

Comment: Serge you didn't include the php script i have with the array of images.

Comment: you didn't had any php earlier, maybe you supposed to put your php inside `code` <div class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">    ? Does php code displays any results? Also you need to wrap all images into  `code`<li>    .. e.g echo ' `code`<li><img src="', $imageDir, '/', $imgPath, '" alt="slide" /></li>'

Comment: @SergePavloff — No, it doesn't. The script has to be loaded before it is used. It does not need to be at the end.